# Table view cell doesn't show updated data

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I reached a correct value and printed it during the debug sessions. However, when i run the application, the calculated value (newcalory) doesn't show up the specific table cell text field. (aka. cell.itemTotalCalory.text) Do you have any ideas for the solution?

*I attached the related code blocks below.

Thanks a lot,

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {

let cell = ingredientTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! IngredientTableViewCell

        cell.ingredientNameTextField.text = ingredients [indexPath.row].ingredientName
        cell.numberofItem.text = "1"
        let cellcalory = ingredients [indexPath.row].ingredientCalory
        cell.itemTotalCalory.text = cellcalory

        cell.plusButton.tag = Int(cell.itemTotalCalory.text!)! //indexPath.row
        cell.plusButton.addTarget(self, action:#selector(plusAction), for: .touchUpInside)
        cell.minusButton.tag = Int(cell.itemTotalCalory.text!)!
        cell.minusButton.addTarget(self, action:#selector(minusAction), for: .touchUpInside)

        return cell
    }


@IBAction func plusAction(sender: UIButton)
    {

        let cell = ingredientTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! IngredientTableViewCell
        let buttonRow = sender.tag

        if cell.numberofItem.text == "1" || cell.numberofItem.text != "1"
        {
            cell.numberofItem.text = "1"
            let textValue1 = cell.numberofItem.text
            var textValue = Int(textValue1!)
            textValue = textValue! + 1
            cell.numberofItem.text = String(describing: textValue)

            let oldcalory = buttonRow
            cell.itemTotalCalory.text = String (((textValue! * Int(oldcalory)) + Int(oldcalory)))
            let newcalory = cell.itemTotalCalory.text

            refresh(newcalory: newcalory!);     

        }
    }

func refresh(newcalory :String)
    {

       let cell = ingredientTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! IngredientTableViewCell
        cell.itemTotalCalory.text = newcalory

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.ingredientTableView.reloadData()
        }    
    }
```

Comment: you need to reload that perticular cell to get updated data

Comment: tableview works on concept of reusability.when the reload the table new cell  created or reused. don't do this. cell.itemTotalCalory.text = newcalory.instead of this save new calory in array or variable.and then set the value in cell.itemTotalCalory.text

Comment: I think that you have a miss understanding of how the UITableView works. In the plusAction you should add a new item to your ingredients array, and then simply call the table to reload the date (what you do in the refresh). The tableview will know that there is one extra item thanks to the datasource and then it will render the extra cell.

Comment: Try those buttonAction logics within IngredientTableViewCell class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, the lines that are listed below are useless.

```
let cell = ingredientTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! IngredientTableViewCell
        cell.itemTotalCalory.text = newcalory
```

I updated the ingredient array with the new value inside the plusAction function  and my problem solved. Thanks for all postings.

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is to update the value in `ingredients` array and then call `ingredientTableView.reloadData()` to reflect this to the UI.

Calling [dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview/1614891-dequeuereusablecell) in `refresh` method will not work as expected for what are you trying to do:

> For performance reasons, a table view’s data source should generally
>   reuse UITableViewCell objects **when it assigns cells to rows in its
>   tableView(_:cellForRowAt:) method**. A table view maintains a queue or
>   list of UITableViewCell objects that the data source has marked for
>   reuse. **Call this method from your data source object when asked to
>   provide a new cell for the table view.** This method dequeues an
>   existing cell if one is available or creates a new one using the class
>   or nib file you previously registered. If no cell is available for
>   reuse and you did not register a class or nib file, this method
>   returns nil.

So, refresh method should be similar to:

```
func refresh() {
    // updating ingredients array upon reqs satisfaction...
    // and then:
    ingredientTableView.reloadData()

    // nameOfYourRefreshControl.endRefreshing()
}
```

Also, if you are pretty sure that you want to get a specific cell from the tableView, you might want to use [cellForRow(at:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview/1614983-cellforrow) instance method:

> Returns the table cell at the specified index path.

```
func refresh() {
    let cell = ingredientTableView?.cellForRow(at: YOUR_INDEX_PATH)

    //...
}
```

Hope this helped.

Comment: Ahmad hi, thanks for your response. You are right about indexPath but i have difficulties to send indexPath.row in cellForRowAt method. I need 'tag' method to send calories to plusAction. When I try to store index path rows in array, i also got error. First, i should send indexPath.row to plusAction and then refresh function. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Could you please elaborate what are you trying to achieve? what I understood is that you have a button on each cell and you want to edit values based on which button has been tapped, if that's it, you need add target to the button and based on what is the tag of it, update a value in the array -for example-...